# MJPG picture in picture

Tags: gstreamer

I've a problem with picture in picture using gstreamer:

I'm using this command to play the stream.

```
gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location='http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg' ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! videomixer name=mix ! autovideosink souphttpsrc location='http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg' ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! mix.
```

But I get the following error:
http://pastebin.com/7Xry2Q8x

Have anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The videomixer wants some sort of framerate information to be delivered to it from each of the streams.  The mjpeg format has none.  Here is a sample that works but assumes a framerate of 30fps.

I also added queue elements before each stream before they connect to the mixer.

> gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc location='http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg' ! multipartdemux ! image/jpeg,framerate=30/1 ! jpegdec ! queue ! videomixer name=mix ! autovideosink sync=false souphttpsrc location='http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg' ! multipartdemux ! image/jpeg,framerate=30/1 ! jpegdec ! queue ! mix.

This kind of pipeline can be tricky to build.  What kind of MJPEGs are you trying to mix?